# Generate cache tiles for EPSG:27700 for use with OpenSpace

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geowebcache, ordnance-survey, os-openspace-api

I am using GeoServer 2.1.0 (Windows Jetty local install for dev), OpenLayers and Ordnance Survey openspace API and have a set of shape data that I am using as an overlay.

Everything is working as expected and drawing correctly but I need to create cached tiles to increase drawing speed.

In understand that the default cache tile generation is either EPSG:4326 or EPSG:900913 and to add EPSG:27700. I understand that this is achieved by creating a geowebcache.xml file containing the definition.

Unfortunately I haven't found an example of a geowebcache.xml file.

I'm not a cartographer just a developer!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you name the layer in geowebcache.xml with a different name to the one in GeoServer.

Hand edit the file

/workspaces////layer.xml and
set the following metadata property:

EPSG:4326,EPSG:900913,EPSG:27700

Comment: Rob - sorry for the long delay but this has been on hold for some time. I've scanned the Geoserver 2.1.0 folder and there is no geowebcache.xml or layer.xml file that I can find!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at OSGB Web Map Tools that Ordnance Survey released last year.

it contains a tutorial and the relevent files to create your own OS OpenSpace

It has an example geowebcache.xml file to use that uses EPSG:27700

Also dont forget to place your geowebcache.xml in the correct folder and restart the service, then when you go into GeoWebCache you should now see EPSG:27700 as an option

Comment: Tim - sorry for the long delay but this has been on hold for some time. I have looked at the OSGB Web Map Tools and I can't quite see why I would want to generate a load of tiles that are already being served to me from the OS system. I can already display shape file data on top of the backgrounds but wanted to cache my data as EPSG:27700 so it displays quicker. So I suppose the question is how do I get geowebcache to allow me to generate tiles other that the standard EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900913 - I would like to see EPSG:27700 in the GeoWebCache Seed page.