# How to load Ordnance Survey OpenSpace in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ordnance-survey, os-openspace-api

The version of gvSIG that I have on my Android tablet will load OS OpenSpace layers and I wonder whether or not it would be possible for QGIS desktop to do the same? And if so, how? I have my own OpenSpace API key.

This appears to be the (long) line in gvSIG's 'layers.txt' file that does the job of fetching the layers:

> 101|Ordnance Survey (UK)
>   OpenSpace;6[>],http://openspace.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/osmapapi/ts?FORMAT=image/png&KEY=#KEY#&URL=#URL#,image/png,11,0,200,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1000000.0,1000000.0,EPSG:27700,2500.0:1000.0:500.0:200.0:100.0:50.0:25.0:10.0:5.0:4.0:2.0:1.0,
>   ,1.1.1,88013ECD7A8F379FE0405F0ACA607F60:8824326E25F94E17E0405F0AC86047BC,http://www.prodevelop.es/maps/map.htm|http://www.gvsigmini.org/maps/map.htm

Comment: You can download the Shapefile versions (March 2011) from http://parlvid.mysociety.org:81/os/ which load straight into Quantum GIS.

Comment: Ah yes, but this is OS OpenData, I was hoping to find a way of loading OpenSpace layers. OpenSpace includes 1:50,000 Landranger mapping. Someone has produced a KML file that will overlay OpenSpace layers on Google Earth  and it would be useful to be able to do the same thing in QGIS. Get osmaps.kml from here: http://www.brock-family.org/gavin/google-earth/osmaps.html. Nick.

Comment: Okay you can use the WMS service to get the tile and view in QGIS http://blog.geo-tag.info/2009/11/29/os-openspace-arcgis-server-javascript-integration/ - more back ground Gavin issues with the OS here http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2009/05/ordnance-survey-kills-openspace-mashup.html

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the link, I'll let you know how I get on with this. Regarding Gavin, the OS have absolute control over what he does and they don't object. In fact, they've increased his tile limit to cater for the extra demand. Nick.

Comment: http://blog.geo-tag.info/2009/11/29/os-openspace-arcgis-server-javascript-integration/ is a very helpful link, for which thanks. Now, as I understand it, I have to do the other half of the job and put together a GDAL web map service XML file. This is well outside of my limited sphere of competence and any pointers would be appreciated. Nick.

Comment: I'm only interested in the 1:50,000 data, which I hope should simplify matters. Nick.

Comment: Hard to answer without access to the OoenSpace API myself, but this should help: http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65244/openlayers-with-uk-ordnance-survey-maps

Comment: May be you need to add GeoServer to your set up, use this for grabbing the OpenSpace data and then opening that through QGIS?  

source - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/generate-cache-tiles-for-epsg27700-for-use-with-openspace

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an OpenSpace user and only dabble in QGIS but this Question has a lot of upvotes and to me if gvSIG can load (= display) via the OS OpenSpace API then it would seem that QGIS should be able to as well.

However, a 50 point bounty failed to uncover an Answer indicating that so my assumption now is that QGIS cannot.

Comment: I still believe it can be done. Your bounty expires in very soon and when this happens I'll start another one running with 500 reps.