# Can I use GeoWebCache with GeoServer Layers which have different native and declared SRS?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, geowebcache

We are using GeoServer to serve raster tiles with a native SRS of 27700, but are forcing use of a declared SRS of 900913.

When I try to seed these tiles using GeoWebCache through the GeoServer web admin interface no tiles are cached. However when I use the native SRS of 27700 seeding works fine.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? And if so, how do I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how force SRS works - that box is for when GeoServer thinks it knows the SRS of your data but is in fact wrong. It allows you as the human in the loop to overrule the program and set the correct SRS.

In your case GeoServer has correctly spotted that your data is in OSGB (27700) and you are telling it to ignore this information and think the the data is in 900913. This will produce the wrong answer!

It's not completely clear what you are trying to achieve - if you want to tile your data as 900913 tiles then I think GWC should handle this out of the box. If you want to tile the data in 27700 (OSGB) then you need to set up a custom tile set (see [Generate cache tiles for EPSG:27700 for use with OpenSpace](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/generate-cache-tiles-for-epsg27700-for-use-with-openspace?rq=1))